# C# компиляция из командной строки (Powershell)

Tags: c#, компиляция, powershell

Итак, дано:

Есть скрипт на повершелле. Путь к компилятору и имя файла. Имя файла передаю параметром к компилятору:

`Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe' -ArgumentList 'PON.cs'`

В результате у меня открывается CMD-окошко (cmd.exe) и быстро закрывается.
Я не понимаю, почему и зачем открывается это новое cmd окошко и почему инфа не отображается в Powerhsell'e.

Хочу чтобы информация о результате выполнения (успешно/ошибка) появлялась в окне Powershell'а и не стартовало новое cmd-окно.

Как это сделать?

Comment: @AK описал. Спасибо за интерес к задаче

Comment: @AK я имел в виду что хочу понимать, что происходит при компиляции - если есть ошибка - увидеть ошибку. Я не знаю как опсиать это другими словами :(

Comment: не знаете как онисать словами - сделайте это скриншотом, покажите что у вас сейчас выводится, и что вы хотите чтобы выводилось

Comment: @AK  Все так, только окошко CMD (консоль по-умолчанибю в виндк)

Answer (score 1):

У вас открывается новое окно потому что вы запускаете exe-файл через Start-Process. А Start-Process по умолчанию открывает новое окно.

Или укажите параметр `-NoNewWindow` (но возможно будет глючить output, если вы не перенаправите его)

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe' -ArgumentList 'PON.cs'
```

Или, что проще, просто вызовите `csc.exe` прямо из powershell:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe PON.cs
```